# optimizing a decryption method in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I need to decrypt large amounts of data quickly using the method below. Currently it takes about 0.3 ms to run with the ICryptoTransform provided. Can someone think any way to optimize it further ? The method is called multiple times in succession with different dataToDecrypt-value but with the same decryptor.

```
public byte[] DecryptUsingDecryptor(byte[] dataToDecrypt, ICryptoTransform decryptor)
    {
        byte[] decryptedData = null;
        MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt,
            decryptor,
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        csDecrypt.Write(dataToDecrypt, 0, dataToDecrypt.Length);
        csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
        decryptedData = msDecrypt.ToArray();
        csDecrypt.Close();
        return decryptedData;
    }
```

Comment: @GungFoo  - I wasn't aware that C# was a script language.....

Comment: No, it is not. Really. Behave yourself.

Comment: @GungFoo this cheap trolling is really inappropriate.

Comment: I don't think you could really optimize this, unless you change the cryptography algorythm used. If you want more "feeling of" performance, you can try to execute it in parallel so that you can use multi-cpu/core architecture

Comment: btw it's a detail but you don't dispose your MemoryStream. Also consider using 'using' block so that streams are also disposed in case of error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if you would notice any performance improvement but if you are using the same `decryptor` couldn't you just re-use the same `msDecrypt` and `csDecrypt` by setting them as private fields?

```
public class Decrypter
{
    private MemoryStream msDecrypt;
    private CryptoStream csDecrypt;

    public Decrypter(ICryptoTransform decryptor)
    {
        msDecrypt = new MemoryStream();
        csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt,decryptor,CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    }

    public byte[] DecryptUsingDecryptor(byte[] dataToDecrypt)
    {
        byte[] decryptedData = null;

        csDecrypt.Write(dataToDecrypt, 0, dataToDecrypt.Length);
        csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
        decryptedData = msDecrypt.ToArray();
        csDecrypt.Close();
        return decryptedData;
    }
}
```

As I said, I don't know if it would make any difference but I think that, at least, you won't be recreating your `MemoryStream` and `CryptoStream` every time.

Comment: Nice idea to test. But then you also need to clear both stream (or at least MemoryStream) otherwise you'll always retrieve data encrypted by previous runs.